# React Native | Hook Component

Tags: react-native, components, hook

Suppose I designed a component for FlatList while using hook in React native. This;
1- It makes more sense to define off the page
or
2- Is it above Return?

Is there any difference between these two users? Which one should be preferred in which situations?

```
//1

const Card = () => (..)

const App = () => {

const RenderItem = () => ( <Card /> )

return(
    <FlatList
      ..
      renderItem={RenderItem}
    >
)}
```

```
//2

const App = () => {

const Card = () => (..)

return(
    <FlatList
      ..
      renderItem={Card}
    >
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 because 1 is using extra method for returning the same component. I would use this way

```
const Card = ({ item }) => (<View key={item.key}></View>);

render(){
  // ...

  <FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={Card}
  />

  // ...
}
```